# Call multiple function with parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function with parameter that is pass as a property:

```
 currentTaskID = null;
 setTaskID = (id) => { 
         this.currentTaskID = id;
         console.log(this.currentTaskID);
         console.log("test");
     }
```

Then on my other component I have a function that needs the event handler and call the prop function when clicked:

```
// select/open task
    openTask = (event) => {
        let targetClass = event.target.classList; 
        if(targetClass.contains('active'))
            targetClass.remove('active')
        else
            targetClass.add('active') 
    }

    // onClick trigger multiple functions
    funcWrapper = (id) => {
        this.openTask();
        this.props.setTaskID.bind(this, id)
    }
```

Onclick:

```
onClick={funcWrapper(id)}
```

error:

```
Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

How can I pass parameters without overwriting the event?

Comment: Do you check id is not `undefined`?

Comment: Yes I checked it's not undefined

Comment: I can't understand your question but looking at the code you're clearly calling the openTask function without the event argument and it clearly must have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggested *Cannot read property 'target' of undefined*. It is not able to find the `target` property in ***undefined***. Because `target` is a property of `event` object. Because `event` has not been passed to the method it is represented with undefined.

I suppose you have to do the call in a anonymous callback:

```
onClick={e => funcWrapper(e, id)}
```

Then pass the event to the method:

```
funcWrapper = (ev, id) => {
    this.openTask(ev);
    this.props.setTaskID(id); // <---as it is in fat arrow syntax no need for bind
}
```

Comment: thank you it solved the error, it calls the openTask function but the prop.setTaskID function is not called.

Comment: @KevinBryan i guess as you have a fat arrow syntax then you don't need the bind.

Comment: @KevinBryan try with `this.props.setTaskID(id)`